# Android Canceling Alarm Manager - Not Working

Tags: android

Alright. I am working on an app where users can schedule times to mute there phones, vibrate there phones, ect...

The app looks good and functions properly, all the way until we get the canceling alarms part of the code.

Here is how I am trying to cancel the alarms.... but it's not working.

```js
 public static void DeleteSpecificAlarm(Context context, int alarmType, int id){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent updateServiceIntent;
        switch(alarmType){
            case 0:
                updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MuteAlarmReciever.class);
                break;
            case 1:
                updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, VibrateAlarmReciever.class);
                break;
            case 2:
                updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, CustomAlarmReciever.class);
                break;
            default:
                updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MuteAlarmReciever.class);
                break;
        }
        PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, id, updateServiceIntent, 0);

        // Cancel alarms
        try {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Manager", "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "AlarmManager update was not canceled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Request: "Include code of your alarm creation."

Here is how I am creating the alarms:

```js
public static void saveNewData(final Context context, final int volumeType, final int volumeLevel, final TimePicker timePicker){
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Schedule");
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if(e == null){
                    final int alarmID = objects.size() + 1;
                    ParseObject scheduledItem = new ParseObject("Schedule");
                    scheduledItem.put("volumeType", volumeType);
                    scheduledItem.put("volumeLevel", volumeLevel);
                    scheduledItem.put("alarmID", alarmID);
                    int hour;
                    int minute;
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
                        hour =  timePicker.getHour();
                        minute = timePicker.getMinute();
                    } else {
                        hour =  timePicker.getCurrentHour();
                        minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

                    }
                    scheduledItem.put("hour", hour);
                    scheduledItem.put("minute", minute);

                    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //Full Current Time
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    Log.i("SchedRinger", "User saved new time. User's selected time was: " + calendar.getTime().toString() + "\n" +
                            "Reciever ID: " + alarmID + "\n" +
                            "Alarm Type: " + volumeType + "\n" +
                            "Volume Level: " + volumeLevel + " (Irrelevent if Alarm Type != 2)");

                    if(hour > 12){
                        if(minute < 10)
                            scheduledItem.put("time",  hour - 12 + ":0" + minute + " PM");
                        else
                            scheduledItem.put("time",  hour - 12 + ":" + minute + " PM");
                    } else {
                        if(minute < 10)
                            scheduledItem.put("time",  hour + ":0" + minute + " PM");
                        else
                            scheduledItem.put("time",  hour + ":" + minute + " PM");
                    }

                    scheduledItem.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if(e == null){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                ScheduleSpecificAlarm(context, calendar, volumeType, volumeLevel, alarmID);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to save. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //TODO: Error
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

```js
private static void ScheduleSpecificAlarm(Context context, Calendar cal, int alarmType, int volumeLevel, int id){

        Intent intentAlarm;

        switch (alarmType){
            case 0:
                intentAlarm = new Intent(context, MuteAlarmReciever.class);
                break;
            case 1:
                intentAlarm = new Intent(context, VibrateAlarmReciever.class);
                break;
            case 2:
                intentAlarm = new Intent(context, CustomAlarmReciever.class);
                intentAlarm.putExtra("volumeLevel", volumeLevel);
                break;
            default:
                intentAlarm = new Intent(context, MuteAlarmReciever.class);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error. Variable passed in wrong on Alarm Creation. Defaulted to 'mute' alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intentAlarm, 0);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Im saving with Parse.com. Which if you do not know the API, just know that you can store and save data in ParseObjects. It's like the Prefs system android hasm but I don't have to worry about sending it via intent.

The Catch Statement is **not** thrown. Why isn't it working? Any ideas?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the catch block does not run? That means the alarm got cancelled and your code works just fine.

Comment: @user13 No. I was just stating that the Try Statement worked successfully, but the code still does not cancel the alarm.

Comment: Ah i see, please show the code where you create the alarms.

Comment: Please show how do you call DeleteSpecificAlarm() also, where do you pass it's parameters from.

Comment: @user13 I added your requests. I use Parse.com's API. It's like the Prefs system android has but I don't have to worry about sending it via intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was actually fairly simple, and one line of code! In the DeleteSpecificAlarm() method I used getService instead of getBroadcast. Changing it fixed the entire thing! Thank you for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 0 in `PendingIntent.getService(context, id, updateServiceIntent, 0);` try using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: Tried... But no success. The ID and AlarmType is definitely getting passed in correctly. I have logs of them and the numbers match up. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) says,`AlarmManager` will call `intent.filterEquals(Intent)` to know if to PendingIntent matches.

I suggest you set a breakpoint at the beginning of `intent.filterEquals(Intent)` and see where it returns false.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I don't quite get the purpose of the functions. I see it returns a boolean and checks to see if two intents are equal to each other, but what other intent am I to compare it with? A example would be best.

Comment: @SizzlingSquiggle `AlarmManager` will try to compare the intent in PendingIntent which you submitted through `AlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent)` to the intent in PendingIntent which you submit earlier through `AlarmManager.setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent)`

Comment: I am confused as to HOW I can compare them, because I apparently I am not getting the reference correctly, so how am I supposed to compare?

Comment: @SizzlingSquiggle just try put a break point in there and see if the program stops, if this approach doesn't work, you can print each intent out and see whats different in them. By "each intent", I mean the one you register alarm with and the one you cancel with.